# Send The Client a Notification after Postback ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, ado.net

I have an `UPDATE` SQL transaction that connects to a SQL Server database using C# .NET 4.0 (I'm currently using  `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` which is not Async so I'm sure I'm gonna need to change it). The transaction execution time is long (about a minute). I have ASP.NET application (Web Forms) and I wish to execute the transaction asynchronously while keeping the user able to interact with the application (navigating through pages). After the execution is finished, I wish to push kind of a notification to the user telling him that the transaction is finished.

I realize that my problem has two parts: the ADO.NET Async part and the part of triggering the application to push a notification to the client when the transaction is complete.

What's the best approach to implement both parts?

Comment: You could use Update Panels in your Asp to fire an Async call to the server. And show some kind of gif while loading. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx and http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers

Comment: SignalR as Dibu suggested would be the ideal solution in your situation, there is a lot of documentation/examples you can find on ASP.net site itself. But specifically mention it (that you do not want to use SignalR) if you are not in favour of making that big of a change to your application.

Comment: You want the user to be able to continue browsing the web while the server is processing a task (can be done). And when then the server task is finished, it has to send a notification to...? Cannot be done.

Comment: This concept of pushing something from the server to the client simply doesn't exist. It is the client (browser) which initiates the interaction with the server. Never the other way around.

Comment: As for the SQL portion of this request, you could look into Asych procedure execution ala this article: http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/.
Per @Dibu, you should look into SignalR for notifying the client when the job is complete running - as they navigate to different pages, it should reconnect on each page load and so be reachable.  However, you might need to have some sort of retry in case they are in between page loads when it completes, or way to abandon if they close their browser and never come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually You can use jquery to do asynchronous call to the method that execute SQL transactions then you will return a message to the user after code execution has been finished.
For more information check the following example 
Jquery Code

```
  $.post( "PageName.aspx/UpdateMethodName", {}) //you can replace method name
   .done(function( data ) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Now in your ASPX page you must have a static method decorated with [WebMethod] attribute

```
[WebMethod]
  public static string UpdateMethodName() //method name will be called from jquery
  {
     // your 
    return "Message";
  }
```

More Information can be found here
[JQuery.Post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

[Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

I hope that help

Answer (score 2):

SignalR will fulfill your requirement

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/315938/Real-time-Asynchronous-Web-Pages-using-jTable-Sign

or after SQl operation you can get response from Executenonquery and save it into hidden field, in client side you can use Jquery setInterval to check th hidden field value